# How to change the SVN URL to commit to?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I have somehow managed to change the remote URL of the SVN repository. Thus, Idea/svn now tries to commit my project to the root of the repository instead of the subfolder that I actually have write access to. How can I change this back? (The URL was originally correct and managed to commit correctly before)

Comment: "somehow" - what does this mean?  Did you do an `svn move` or something?

Comment: Frankly, I don't remember. Besides doing commits, I only looked around the repository, not changing any settings -- or so I thought. I just assume that the setting didn't change by itself. BTW, I only used Idea's controls and not `svn` itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Repository URL is stored in the working copy metadata, IDEA doesn't change it automatically. You can change it manually from IntelliJ IDEA using the `VCS` | `Subversion` | **Relocate** menu.

It can also be done from the command line with [svn relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) or Tortoise SVN `Relocate...` menu.

Comment: Turns out that my problem is something else after all, but still thanks.

Comment: My relocate fails with E155024 : Invalid relocation destination

Comment: VCS | Subversion | Relocate menu. nothing open

Comment: I have got the same error  E155024 : Invalid relocation destination. To solve the problem and change the URL location, I deleted the .svn folder and the svn.xml file of Android Studio IDEA

Answer (score 2):

If your project is not stored at the root of your repository (ex: `my-svn-repo/my-project/trunk`)
and, for example, you renamed `my-project`to `my-awesome-project` then the Relocate functionality wont work because it's related to a repository and not its sub-folders. In this case you will have to do a "Switch" using:

- IntelliJ Idea : VCS > Update Project > Select the newly renamed folder or;
- Tortoise SVN : Switch > Select the new folder